# Javascript toFixed() issues

Tags: javascript, parsefloat, tofixed

I am having trouble with my toFixed() method.  Before I added it onto all the parseFloats, which were already there, it was displaying all the totals but with too many decimal places.  Now it displays nothing. When I take the toFixed() off, it displays like it should.  Console is telling me "total.tofixed" is not a function, but this part was working before I added in the other 6 toFixed() commands. Here is my code

```
var rent = prompt ("Enter your total rent");
var food = prompt ("Enter your total food expenditures");
var utilities = prompt ("Enter your total utilities costs");
var transport = prompt ("Enter your total transportations costs");
var internet = prompt ("Enter your internet and cable costs");
var other = prompt ("Enter an estimated total for all other expenditures");

rent = parseFloat(rent).toFixed(2);
food = parseFloat(food).toFixed(2);
utilities = parseFloat(utilities).toFixed(2);
transport = parseFloat(transport).toFixed(2);
internet = parseFloat(internet).toFixed(2);
other = parseFloat(other).toFixed(2);

var total = rent + food + utilities + transport + other; 
total = total.toFixed(2); //determines "total" variable will use 2 decimal places
document.write(total);


var rentPerc = (rent / total)*100;
var foodPerc = (food / total)*100;
var utPerc = (utilities / total)*100;
var transPerc = (transport / total)*100;
var internetPerc = (internet / total)*100;
var otherPerc = (other / total)*100;
var totalPerc = rentPerc + foodPerc + utPerc + transPerc + internetPerc +otherPerc;
document.write("Total rent:", rent, rentPerc, "Total food", food, foodPerc, "Total utilities:",
utilities, utPerc, "Total transportation:", transport, transPerc, "Total            internet:", internet, 
internetPerc, "Total other:", other, otherPerc, "Total expenditures:", total,     totalPerc);
```

Comment: You need to convert those strings back to numbers: `... = +rent + +food + +utilities + +transport + +other;`.

Answer (score 2):

> but this part was working before I added in the other 6 toFixed() commands

Right. `toFixed()` is a method on **numbers**. `toFixed()` returns a **string**. So `rent + food` is not performing addition, it's performing string concatenation.

Only call `toFixed()` on the values that you want to *display*. Don't use its return value for any computations.

Answer (score 1):

I have made only 1 change used **parseFloat** before passing the parameter to **toFixed**

```
total = total.toFixed(2); //determines "total" variable will use 2 decimal places
```

to

```
total = parseFloat(total).toFixed(2); //determines "total" variable will use 2 decimal places
```

Here is your whole updated code again

```
var rent = prompt ("Enter your total rent");
var food = prompt ("Enter your total food expenditures");
var utilities = prompt ("Enter your total utilities costs");
var transport = prompt ("Enter your total transportations costs");
var internet = prompt ("Enter your internet and cable costs");
var other = prompt ("Enter an estimated total for all other expenditures");

rent = parseFloat(rent).toFixed(2);
food = parseFloat(food).toFixed(2);
utilities = parseFloat(utilities).toFixed(2);
transport = parseFloat(transport).toFixed(2);
internet = parseFloat(internet).toFixed(2);
other = parseFloat(other).toFixed(2);

var total = rent + food + utilities + transport + other; 
total = parseFloat(total).toFixed(2); //determines "total" variable will use 2 decimal places
document.write(total);


var rentPerc = (rent / total)*100;
var foodPerc = (food / total)*100;
var utPerc = (utilities / total)*100;
var transPerc = (transport / total)*100;
var internetPerc = (internet / total)*100;
var otherPerc = (other / total)*100;
var totalPerc = rentPerc + foodPerc + utPerc + transPerc + internetPerc +otherPerc;
document.write("Total rent:", rent, rentPerc, "Total food", food, foodPerc, "Total utilities:",
utilities, utPerc, "Total transportation:", transport, transPerc, "Total            internet:", internet, 
internetPerc, "Total other:", other, otherPerc, "Total expenditures:", total,     totalPerc);
```

Comment: Still not going to work. `var total = rent + food + ...` will concatenate strings.

Comment: @Maria please accept the answer as correct if you find it useful. it motivates people for answering your questions.

Comment: You can edit your question if you have more queries.

Answer (score 0):

`toFixed()` returns number as string, if you will compare numbers, you need to use `parseFloat` again.

The alternative is

```
yourString= parseFloat((yourString).toFixed(2));
```

Comment: thanks, i tried this but what ended up working for me was doing the parseFloats first, then the calculations, then finally the toFixed, separately.

Answer (score 0):

The method `toFixed(decimals)` converts your number to a string. So in your `total` var you're concatenating strings instead of adding. You're getting
`"total.tofixed" is not a function`because a string doesn't have a `toFixed()` method.